# Count number occurrences of each string in a column

Tags: excel

I have an excel table which contains information about bugs containing columns such as `Product`, `Owner`, etc.

The `Product` column contains values (strings) such as `PTS`, `SDE`, etc.

How do I find the count of occurrences of each of product (PTS or SDE)?

For example, the following table -

```
    ╔════╦══════════════╦═════════╗
    ║ id ║  Product     ║    Owner║
    ╠════╬══════════════╬═════════╣
    ║  1 ║    PTS       ║    thiru║
    ║  2 ║    PTS       ║  sajeesh║
    ║  3 ║    SDE       ║    varun║
    ║  4 ║    SPB       ║  ranjith║
    ╚════╩══════════════╩═════════╝
```

when queried for `Product` column would return

```
PTS - 2
SDE - 1
SPB - 1
```

Comment: COUNTIF(): https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIF-function-e0de10c6-f885-4e71-abb4-1f464816df34 there is a nice little video.

Comment: PivotTable should be easier or the usual `= CountIf( B2:B5, "PTS" )`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest solutions are PivotTable, Power Query, PowerPivot, etc. 
Unlike the formula solutions, they do not auto-update when the source range is changed, but you can configure how often they are refreshed or refresh them manually.

Comment: Thanks @Slai. PivotTable says "The field you are dropping into the column area exceeds 256 items". Is that a limitation? Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @thiru Yes, [Value fields in a PivotTable report](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3) are limited to 256. You can use row fields or try the PowerPivot/Power Query add-ins

Answer (score 1):

```
Product           Formula                            Result
PTS               =countif(Product_Range, "PTS")     2 
SDE               =countif(Product_Range, "SDE")     1
SPB               =countif(Product_Range, "SPB")     1
```

The `countif` formula is looking through the data range with product names, and counting the number of items that matches the name you specified in the formula.

Here are the arguments that `countif` takes

```
=countif(range, criteria)
```

Comment: Thanks @davidhu2000, but how to get the occurrence count for all the products in a single query?